# Tmux Select Pane not properly setting default bg/fg color

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, tmux

I have a heavily customized tmux config that changes colors depending on which user I'm using (e.g., turns bg to red when I'm sudoing root).

For years I've been using `select-pane -P` to temporarily set the background color for the current pane, and at a later stage I revert back by using `select-pane -P 'bg=default,fg=default'`.

Something changed in tmux 3.0a that broke my config. In tmux 2.7, the `select-pane -P bg=default` would return to the color I had defined earlier for `window-style`, as one would expect (after all it was the default color for all windows).

In tmux 3.0a, the `-P bg=default` now reverts **to the color used in the shell *before* starting tmux**, which is definitely not what I expect.

To reproduce:

**Using tmux 2.7**

```bsh
/usr/bin/tmux
tmux set -g window-style 'fg=colour231,bg=colour67'  # default color - e.g. blue bg
tmux select-pane -P 'bg=#441414'                     # temporary pane bg color - e.g., red
tmux select-pane -P 'bg=default,fg=default'          # reverts back to "default" (i.e., blue)
```

**Using tmux 3.0a**

```bsh
/usr/bin/tmux
tmux set -g window-style 'fg=colour231,bg=colour67'  # default color - e.g. blue bg
tmux select-pane -P 'bg=#441414'                     # temporary pane bg color - e.g., red
tmux select-pane -P 'bg=default,fg=default'          # >> reverts to the _color used before starting tmux_!
```

Any ideas what was done in 3.0 that has changed the default behavior, or any suggestions how to better troubleshoot this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the default changed from`window-style` to the actual terminal default colour which may or may not have been intentional...

You should be able to do  `set -up window-style ; set -up window-active-style` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Replacing the last `select-pane -P 'bg=default,fg=default'` with `set -up window-style ; set -up window-active-style` worked perfectly.